# Currently struggling to use media queries to create dynamic layout changes when screen sizes change

Tags: html, css

I've managed to become ok at HTML and CSS and would like some assistance making this code responsive in the way I've designed it in photoshop. But media queries keep getting override and I would love some guidance into how to overcome and also how to make my code better for what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Londrina+Solid:wght@300&display=swap');
html * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

.midsmallprint {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #f1d036;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #72c789;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #d04a30;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #e7e1c5;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #2c7841;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: #c55f4b;
}

/* mid carousel*/

.midtopcarousel ul {
    width: 600px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.midtopcarousel ul li {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.midtopcarousel ul li span {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: SF Pro Display;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}


/* mid image header */

.midimage ul li h1 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: flex;
    font-family: "Londrina Solid", cursive;
    justify-content: center;
}


/* mid big image */

.midimage {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 360px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.midsection .midimage li span {
    font-family: SF Pro Display;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

/* mid INGREDIENTS */

.midimageingre ul li span {
    font-family: SF Pro Display;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.midimageingre ul li .price {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "Barlow Condensed", sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline-block;
}

.midimageingre ul li .ingname {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: right;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
}

.midimageingre ul {
    display: grid;
    clear: both;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 26px;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    float: right;
    font-family: "Londrina Solid", cursive;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    clear: none;
}
.midimageingre ul li {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #555;
}

.midsection {
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #f0efef;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:540px) {
   
    .midsmallprint {
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #e5509a;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: x-small;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
    }
    .midsection {
        padding-right: 20px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f1ed00;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
    .midimage {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 360px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .midimageingre ul li span {
        font-family: SF Pro Display;
        margin-left: 10px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .midimageingre ul li .price {
        font-weight: 900;
        font-family: "Barlow Condensed", sans-serif;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .midimageingre ul li .ingname {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: normal;
        margin-right: 20px;
        float: right;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .midimageingre ul li {
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 30px;
        background: rgb(125, 214, 103);
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .midimage {}
    .midimageingre ul {}
    .midimageingre ul li {}
    .left li {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: white;
    }
   
    /* showcase */
    .midsection {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        order: 3;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class="midsection">
            <div class="midtopcarousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><span>x</span></li>
                    <li><span>x</span></li>
                    <li><span>x</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="midimageingre">
                <ul>
                    <li><span>x</span>
                        <div class="price">50p</div>
                        <div class="ingname ">CHEESE</div>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>x</span>
                        <div class="price">50p</div>
                        <div class="ingname ">LETTUCE</div>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>x</span>
                        <div class="price">50p</div>
                        <div class="ingname ">TOMATOES</div>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>x</span>
                        <div class="price">50p</div>
                        <div class="ingname ">ONIONS</div>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>x</span>
                        <div class="price">50p</div>
                        <div class="ingname ">CUCUMBERS</div>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>x</span>
                        <div class="price">50p</div>
                        <div class="ingname ">SAUCE</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="midimage">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>x</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Name Of Burger</h1>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="midsmallprint">* alterations to items will affect price</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Avoid empty selectors like `.midimage {}`, first. I suggest to implement either `grid` or `flexbox` (see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) here: media queries themselves seem to be OK, as you started from the smaller to the bigger viewport.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**  Based on the Edit from OP (i-e Images provided) I have updated my code to work for all the 4 break-points. Here is the updated Code:)

CODEPEN LINK : https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/mdrLMde

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Londrina+Solid:wght@300&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.midsection {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.midsmallprint {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-small;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.midimageingre {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 2rem;
}
.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #f1d036;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #72c789;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #d04a30;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #e7e1c5;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #2c7841;
}

.midimageingre ul li:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: #c55f4b;
}

/* mid carousel*/

.midtopcarousel ul li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.midtopcarousel ul li span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: SF Pro Display;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/* mid image header */

.midimage ul li {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: "Londrina Solid", cursive;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.midimage ul li span {
  color: #000 !important;
}

/* mid big image */

.midimage {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  min-height: 75vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar {
  padding: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.sidebar li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.midsection .midimage li span {
  font-family: SF Pro Display;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/* mid INGREDIENTS */

.midimageingre ul li span {
  font-family: SF Pro Display;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.midimageingre ul li .price {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Barlow Condensed", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

.midimageingre ul li .ingname {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.midimageingre ul {
  font-family: "Londrina Solid", cursive;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.midimageingre ul li {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #555;
  margin: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.sidebar li {
  display: flex !important;
  margin: 1rem 0 !important;
  justify-content: space-around !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.midsection {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f0efef;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .midimageingre {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }

  .midimageingre .sidebar {
    order: -1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .midimageingre .sidebar {
    order: 1;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .midimageingre .sidebar {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    column-gap: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quantico&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="midsection">
      <div class="midtopcarousel">
        <ul>
          <li><span>x</span></li>
          <li><span>x</span></li>
          <li><span>x</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="midimageingre">
        <div class="midimage">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span>x</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h1>Name Of Burger</h1>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="sidebar">
          <li>
            <span>x</span>
            <div class="price">50p</div>
            <div class="ingname">CHEESE</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>x</span>
            <div class="price">50p</div>
            <div class="ingname">LETTUCE</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>x</span>
            <div class="price">50p</div>
            <div class="ingname">TOMATOES</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>x</span>
            <div class="price">50p</div>
            <div class="ingname">ONIONS</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>x</span>
            <div class="price">50p</div>
            <div class="ingname">CUCUMBERS</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>x</span>
            <div class="price">50p</div>
            <div class="ingname">SAUCE</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="midsmallprint">* alterations to items will affect price</div>
    </div>
```

There are couple of things I would like to point.

1. Using floats when you are using flexbox and grids doesn't make much sense. Flexbox and CSS-Grids came to overcome the issues that were there in the float layouts.
2. Media Queries should be used properly in a way that One of the Layout is ready say a Desktop Layout is ready. Then we need pretty small small changes in our media queries as per our small screen, because all the CSS is already there. We just need to change only those things that we don't need on smaller screens.

I have made a CODEPEN Demo for your code :) Changed HTML Element positions a bit, Removed un-necessary CSS like floats. And now you can build on top of it :)